# Error saving two forms in one template in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a view with 2 form. The forms doesn't have any related fields.

form 1:
Have a FilteredSelectMultiple widget showing some files to download from a ftp server. Every file in this form match some criteria

form 2:
Have a FilteredSelectMultiple widget showing files that doesn't match any criteria from the same FTP server

I have 3 scenarios:

1. The user must select one or more files from the form 1 and leave the
   pther form empty
2. The user must select one or more files from the form 2 and leave the
   other form empty
3. Select Files from the 2 forms.

Every form must work individually

This is my view:

```
 @login_required(login_url='/login/')
    def archivoview2(request):
        usuario = request.user
        nomigrado = Archivo_NoMigrado()
        spnm = nomigrado.archivos_nomig()
        form = ProcFTPForm(usuario,prefix='f')
        form2 = DesconocidoForm2(initial={'usuario':usuario},prefix='d')

        if request.method == 'POST':
           if form.is_valid():
              form.save()
        if request.method == 'POST' and not form.is_valid():
           form = ProcFTPForm(usuario,request.POST)
           form2 = DesconocidoForm2(request.POST)
           if form2.is_valid():
              form2.save()
     #--Run stored procedure for files matching criteria---   
              proc = Lista_Final()
              lista = proc.archivos()
              tabla = Proc_Carga()
              sp = tabla.carga()
     #--Run Stored Procedures for unknown files------
              carga = Carga_Unknown()
              spcarga = carga.desconocido()
              return HttpResponseRedirect('/resumen/')

        if request.method == 'POST' and not form2.is_valid():
           form = ProcFTPForm(usuario,request.POST)
           form2 = DesconocidoForm2(request.POST)
           if form.is_valid():
              form.save()
         #--Run stored procedure for files matching criteria---
              proc = Lista_Final()
              lista = proc.archivos()
              tabla = Proc_Carga()
              sp = tabla.carga()
              return HttpResponseRedirect('/resumen/')
        return render_to_response("archivo2.html",
                          {'form':form,'form2':form2},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

When I choose files only from the form 1 works fine
but when I try to save the two forma at the same time I get the error
**File required** in every field from the two forms.

At least I need to complete two scenarios:

1. Save the two forms
   or
2. Save only the form 1

Any advice

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Why do you keep re-instantiating the forms inside the is_valid blocks?

Comment: Well @DanielRoseman I was testing instantianing the forms. But doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to simplify all those `if request.method=='POST' ...` conditions. Here's how I handle multiple forms. I don't know if this is is exactly the canonical way of handling two forms, but it seems quite clean. Obviously, this is doesn't have all of your 'run stored procedure' commands, or your redirects.

```
form = ProcFTPForm(usuario,prefix='f')
form2 = DesconocidoForm2(initial={'usuario':usuario},prefix='d')
if request.method=='POST':
    form = ProcFTPForm(request.POST, usuario)
    form2 = DesconocidoForm2(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    if form2.is_valid():
        form2.save()
else:
    template = 'archivo2.html'
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'form2': form2,
    }
return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: Not quite. You should move the first two lines into the else block; and you definitely need to remember to pass the prefix to DesconocidoForm2 on POST as well.